# Python : Type error: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python

So my following code has a callable type error and I do not understand why(Or what it is):

```
         file1 = open("File1.txt","r")
    sent = file1.readlines()
    sent = str(sent).lower().split()
    u=0

    ofile = open("Encoded.txt","r")
    decode = ofile.readlines()
    decode = str(decode).split()
    u = 0
    decode(0)==sent(0)<=== #Error here
    while u < len(decode):
        u = u+1
        decode(u) == sent(u)<== #Error here
```

How would I fix this issue?

Comment: Not related to your main issue, but are you aware of the output of this line: `sent = str(sent).lower().split()` ?

Comment: List indexing is with `[]` not `()`

Answer (score 0):

'decode' and 'sent' are lists but you use them like a function. If you want to access index of a list, use [] intead:

```
decode[u] == sent[u]
```

Anyway you are doing something very weird with the decode = str(decode).split(), I don't think "decode" looks as you expect it to look.
And on a side note, you might want to replace your while statement with:

```
for u in range(len(decode))
```

But its less important.